# Stop flex items stacking on top of each other

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get to grips with `flex` and am struggling to create what I'm after.

### What I'm trying to do

- Full screen container
- Two `div` elements, one right-aligned with a width of `640px` and one left-aligned taking the remaining space

### What's happening

My elements are displaying, on top of one another, in the centre of the screen.

### Code

```css
div.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
}
div.hero {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
div.timeline {
  width: 640px;
  margin: auto;
}
div.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  /* color: #fff; */
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  /* Safari */
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, calc(-50% - 66px));
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, calc(-50% - 66px));
  /* Safari */
  transform: translate(0, calc(-50% - 66px));
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

  <div class="hero">

    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- End header -->

    <!-- Timeline -->
    <div class="timeline">
      <ul class="timeline-both-side">
        <li>
          <div class="border-line"></div>
          <div class="timeline-description">
            <p>Quisque ac laoreet purus, eu dapibus ligula. Mauris nec tincidunt mi, eget finibus sem. Morbi viverra malesuada lobortis. Suspendisse sed augue luctus ex molestie convallis.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="opposite-side">
          <div class="border-line"></div>
          <div class="timeline-description">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed erat consectetur, tempor odio sit amet, euismod sapien.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="border-line"></div>
          <div class="timeline-description">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed erat consectetur, tempor odio sit amet, euismod sapien.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="opposite-side">
          <div class="border-line"></div>
          <div class="timeline-description">
            <p>Quisque ac laoreet purus, eu dapibus ligula. Mauris nec tincidunt mi, eget finibus sem. Morbi viverra malesuada lobortis. Suspendisse sed augue luctus ex molestie convallis.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="border-line"></div>
          <div class="timeline-description">
            <p>Quisque ac laoreet purus, eu dapibus ligula. Mauris nec tincidunt mi, eget finibus sem. Morbi viverra malesuada lobortis. Suspendisse sed augue luctus ex molestie convallis.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End timeline -->

  </div>

</div>
```

### Question

How can I use `flex` to have these two elements, both with `100vh`, in a row like below?

```
+------------------------------------------+
|.flex                                     |
|+-------------------------+ +------------+|
||.hero                    | |.timeline   ||
||                         | |            ||
||                         | |            ||
|+-------------------------+ +------------+|
+------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplicity itself.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}
.hero {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}
.timeline {
  flex: 0 0 640px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="hero"></div>
  <div class="timeline"></div>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yewrvP)

Answer (score 4):

Consider these adjustments to your CSS:

```
div.flex {
    display: flex;
    /* flex-direction: row;   <-- not necessary; default value */
    /* flex-wrap: nowrap;     <-- not necessary; default value */
    /* align-items: stretch;  <-- not necessary; default value */
    height: 100vh;
}

div.hero {
    display: flex;                   /* nested flex container */
    justify-content: space-around;   /* moved here from div.flex, but not even necessary */
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center bottom;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    /* margin: auto; <-- REMOVE */
}

div.timeline {
    width: 640px;
    /* margin: auto; <-- REMOVE */
}

div.header {
    flex: 1;              
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/fn5u6mLz/)

NOTES:

- When you create a flex container (by applying `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex` to an element), the *child elements* become flex items. The descendants of the flex container beyond the children do not become flex items and, therefore, do not accept flex properties.

  In your code, `div.flex` is the flex container. This means that its only child – `div.hero` – is a flex item. The children of `div.hero`, however, are not flex items. They remain standard block elements, which is why they are stacking vertically.

  Make `div.hero` a (nested) flex container, so that its children become flex items.
- `margin: auto` centers a flex item in the container. This doesn't appear to be what you want, so remove it.
- The absolute positioning applied to `.header` isn't necessary.
- `flex: 1` tells a flex item to consume all available space in the container.

Answer (score 1):

You structure was not correct, `.flex` had only one child: `.hero`

You can simplify the CSS and break into 2 child containers `.hero` & `.timeline`

```css
div.flex {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
div.hero {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;/* will use whole space left avalaible */
  margin: auto;
}
div.timeline {
  width: 640px;/* flex values are not usefull here since you want a static width */
  margin: auto;
}
div.header {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

  <div class="hero">

    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- End header -->
  </div>
  <!-- end hero -->

  <!-- Timeline -->
  <div class="timeline">
    <ul class="timeline-both-side">
      <li>
        <div class="border-line"></div>
        <div class="timeline-description">
          <p>Quisque ac laoreet purus, eu dapibus ligula. Mauris nec tincidunt mi, eget finibus sem. Morbi viverra malesuada lobortis. Suspendisse sed augue luctus ex molestie convallis.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="opposite-side">
        <div class="border-line"></div>
        <div class="timeline-description">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed erat consectetur, tempor odio sit amet, euismod sapien.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="border-line"></div>
        <div class="timeline-description">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sed erat consectetur, tempor odio sit amet, euismod sapien.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="opposite-side">
        <div class="border-line"></div>
        <div class="timeline-description">
          <p>Quisque ac laoreet purus, eu dapibus ligula. Mauris nec tincidunt mi, eget finibus sem. Morbi viverra malesuada lobortis. Suspendisse sed augue luctus ex molestie convallis.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="border-line"></div>
        <div class="timeline-description">
          <p>Quisque ac laoreet purus, eu dapibus ligula. Mauris nec tincidunt mi, eget finibus sem. Morbi viverra malesuada lobortis. Suspendisse sed augue luctus ex molestie convallis.</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- End timeline -->

</div>
```